# A problem related to 2D Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, projectile

> Q. Two balls are fired from ground level, at a distance d apart. The right one is fired vertically with speed $v$. You wish to simultaneously project the left one at an appropriate velocity $u$ so that it collides with the right ball when they reach their highest point. For $D$ = 10 m, what should $v$ (in m/s) be so that the speed $u$ is minimum?

Figure made with Paint 3D (not to scale):

[image]
I came up with:

$$\text{Height}=\frac{u^2\sin^2(\theta)}{2g}=\frac{v^2}{2g}$$

since, the maximum height of both the balls have to be the same.

$$\implies u^2 \sin^2 \theta=v^2 $$

$$\implies (u\sin\theta)^2=v^2$$

$$\implies u \sin \theta=v=u_y$$

I am stuck at, *what should $v$ (in m/s) be so that the speed $u$ is minimum?*

According to my understanding, to determine $u$ we have to determine the angle at which it was projected. That angle will then depend on the velocity of the ball with velocity, $v$. But, I can't decrease $\theta$ infinitely to reduce the value of $u$ and, thus, the value of $v$, so, there must be something I am missing.

Also, are there any other parameters that could influence the value of $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 0):

That is one constraint that you got now. In order to find a relation between $u$ and $v$, $\theta$ has to be eliminated. This can be done with a second constraint which uses the range. Since ball 1 reaches the highest point at half the range and given that $D=10$, the next constraint can be
$$\frac{u^2\sin(2\theta)}{2g} = 10.$$
Using this relation $\theta$ can be eliminated from the first constraint and a relation between $u$ and $v$ can be obtained. It is then a simple problem of calculating the minimum value of $u$ and the corresponding $v$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constraint that they should reach that point simultaneously for collision to happen. that is the time taken will be equal.